# How to jump automatically to the next “TEdit” after this input finish when i use c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to realize a license function. I use five `TEdit` control, and how to jump automatically to the next `TEdit` after this input finish.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
__published:
    TEdit *Edit1;
    TEdit *Edit2;
    TEdit *Edit3;
    TEdit *Edit4;
    TEdit *Edit5;
    void __fastcall EditChange(TObject *Sender);
private:
    TEdit *Edits[5];
    int __fastcall IndexOf(TEdit *Edit);
public:
    __fastcall TMyForm(TComponent *Owner);
}
```

```
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Edits[0] = Edit1;
    Edits[1] = Edit2;
    Edits[2] = Edit3;
    Edits[3] = Edit4;
    Edits[4] = Edit5;
}

int __fastcall TMyForm::IndexOf(TEdit *Edit)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if (Edits[i] == Edit)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

// assign this single OnChange event handler to the 5 TEdit controls...
void __fastcall TMyForm::EditChange(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit *ThisEdit = static_cast<TEdit*>(Sender);
    if (ThisEdit->GetTextLen() >= ThisEdit->MaxLength)
    {
        int idx = IndexOf(ThisEdit);
        if (idx != -1)
        {
            if (idx < 4)
                Edits[idx+1]->SetFocus();
            else
                OkButton->SetFocus(); // or whatever you want to do after the last input...
        }   
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Edit1->Tag = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(static_cast<TControl*>(Edit2));
    Edit2->Tag = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(static_cast<TControl*>(Edit3));
    Edit3->Tag = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(static_cast<TControl*>(Edit4));
    Edit4->Tag = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(static_cast<TControl*>(Edit5));
    Edit5->Tag = 0; // or whatever control you want focused after the last input...
}

// assign this single OnChange event handler to the 5 TEdit controls...
void __fastcall TMyForm::EditChange(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit *ThisEdit = static_cast<TEdit*>(Sender);
    if (ThisEdit->GetTextLen() >= ThisEdit->MaxLength)
    {
        TControl *NextControl = reinterpret_cast<TControl*>(ThisEdit->Tag);
        if (NextControl)
            NextControl->SetFocus();
        else
            // whatever you want to do after the last input...
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
// configure the tab stops on the TEdit (and other controls) as desired,
// and assign this single OnChange event handler to the 5 TEdit controls...
void __fastcall TMyForm::EditChange(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit *ThisEdit = static_cast<TEdit*>(Sender);
    if (ThisEdit->GetTextLen() >= ThisEdit->MaxLength)
        SelectNext(ThisEdit, true, true);
}
```